# Calculation of precalculated values PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

i'm trying to do two calculations in one procedure in pl/sql. The simple version would look like

```
select a1+a2
into a
from table c;

select b1+b2
into b
from table c;
```

...
in the end i would like to further calculate the results of a and b, so let's say

```
select (a*b) 
into c
from x

insert 
into x (A,B,C)
values (a,b,c)
```

would that be possible? In case I split the two into two procedures (to first calculate a, b and then a second procedure to calculate c) i got results like

```
 A   | B    | C 
 a   | b    | null 
null | null | c
```

what i want to get is

```
A   | B  | C 
a   | b  | c
```

Comment: Why a stored procedure? What do it in three steps? Why not simply use a single statement:`insert into x (a,b,c) select a1+a2, b1+b2, (a1+a2 * b1+b2) from c`

Comment: Hi, it's just a simple version of what I have, the first calculation of values is over 1000 lines long in my query. So for the sake of clarity I'd like to find more 'clean' solution to that.

Comment: While the above comment gives you the best way of doing this, the reason you're getting the nulls you are is that you're inserting with your second procedure rather than updating the existing record.  The last command in your second paragraph should be Update 'X' Set 'C' = c Where 'A' = a and 'B' = b;

Comment: Great! that'd solve my issue :) Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, if you just want to update column 'C' for all the records where it's value is null you could just type 'Update X Set C = a * b Where C is NULL;